# How to get answer from google form through question title

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am integrating google form with the backend system. For that, I need google form response in the key-value pair. Is there any way to get form response in the key-value pair?

**I am trying this:**

```
var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
var questions = e.source.getItems();
Logger.log(questions[1].getTitle());
Logger.log(itemResponses[0].getResponse());
```

When i am accessing the answer from response using namedValues it is throwing

> `TypeError: Cannot read property "Question Title" from undefined.`

**Code for accessing answer for questions:**

```
Logger.log(e.getNamedValues[questions[1].getTitle()][0]);
```

Comment: You provided a line of code: `Logger.log(e.getNamedValues[questions[1].getTitle()][0]);`  There is no `getNamedValues` property of any event object.  [Link to documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)  There *is* a `namedValues` property for a **spreadsheet** On Form Submit event, but *not* a **Form** On Form Submit event.  So, you can't use `e.namedValues` in code bound to a Form.  Is your code bound to a Google Sheet or Form?

Comment: My code is bound to a google form. It is any way to fetch response along with the question?

Comment: Try following this guide on how to get [`itemResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response).This will help you check if your code is correct. AFAIK, it should be `itemResponse.getItem().getTitle()`.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Rebot